# Fix Faq Ask Email Layout Question

Tags: 7, emails

I am using [FAQ Ask](http://drupal.org/project/faq_ask) along with the [FAQ module](http://drupal.org/project/faq). Everything works well but the emails are coming all bunched up. I need to be able to re-arrange the layout as I want (simple text with active links).

Below is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These emails are assembled in the **faq_ask_mail** function (faq_ask,nodule, line 1013). The body is assembled beginning at line 1077.

If you wish to open up the body, you can go in and include some newline ('\n') characters into the text.

Since this hacks the module core, perhaps you should submit a patch as a [feature request](http://drupal.org/project/faq_ask).

EDIT:

**faq_ask_mail** is an implementation of [hook_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7). You can define your own hook_mail in a custom module to override the output. You must, however, adjust the weight of your custom module so it is processed after the faq_ask module. You would handle it as follows:

```
function MYMODULE_mail(&$key, &$message, &$params) {
  $body = $message['body'];
  switch ($key) {
    case 'notify_expert':
    case 'notify_asker' :
      /*** Change the formatting of $body ***/
      $body = str_replace("\.", "\.\n\n", $body);
      break;
  }
  $message['body'] = $body;
}
```

Remember that this will have no effect if it is executed before the faq_ask_mail function.

Comment: Are you saying that the only way to fix this is by patching this module? Can it be creating a custom module instead?

Comment: No, just the most direct. See my edit above.